# Creating list of widgtets draggable

Tags: flutter, dart

My idea is to create a few (the same, with different index) draggable objects. It works perfectly when I write in stack: object1, object2, object3... but if I set a list of them dragging doesn't work properly. After dragging object disappears.

This works, object disappears after dragging:

```
match(int i) {
    return Positioned(
        top: top[i],
        left: left[i],
        child: Draggable(
          data: 10,
          onDragUpdate: (details) {
            top[i] = top[i] + details.delta.dy;
            left[i] = left[i] + details.delta.dx;
            print('${top[i]}, ${left[i]}');
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: Material(
              child: Container(
                  height: 50, width: 50, child: Image.asset('match.jpg'))),
          feedback: Material(
              child: Container(
                  height: 50, width: 50, child: Image.asset('match.jpg'))),
        ));
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Stack(
              children: [match(0), match(1), match(2)],
            );
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
List<Widget> listOfMatches = [];
  List<double> top = [];
  List<double> left = [];

  bool created = false;
  createListOfMatches() {
    if (!created) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        top.add(200);
        left.add(200);
        listOfMatches.add(match(i));
      }
      setState(() {
        created = true;
      });
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: createListOfMatches(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Stack(
              children: listOfMatches,
            );
          }),
}
```

What I need is a list of objects so I can pass a number of them from previous screen
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems you should use the `onDragEnd` callback, the `DraggableDetails` has an `offset` property which you could set to the `top` and `left` variable.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:
For now this works for me

```
Stack(
                children: [
                  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) match(i)
                ],
```